# Is there a way to store Path and Paint of CustomPainter in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm using CustomPainter to make a screen where user can paint with a finger or stylus. Not a rocket science so far.

Drawn lines are stored as

```
List<MapEntry<Path, Paint>>
```

Of'cause I can export this "drawing" and .png but I would like to store Path and Paint in order to load the drawing back in canvas later on to draw on further.

My idea, I could convert the objects into a kind of byte array and store them in DB or file but it did not work out.

I also cannot make a json out of it.

Is there a way to store such objects in Flutter or should I store points the use pass through during drawing and rebuild paths from there?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, do you find a solution for this?

Comment: yes, finally I had updated the library by myself to achieve this. It was already more than half a year ago. if you are interested, I can try to figure out the solution

Comment: Please my friend, i really need help with this

Comment: ok, have a look on the answer please

Answer (score 1):

As I have not found a solution that time, I decided to realise it by myself.

I cloned Painter2 lib and modified it's code to add the following functionality:

- add a dot on screen by single tap
- add save / restore functionality for path in order to reload your painting for later edit.

The lib is available here
https://github.com/fellow7000/painter2
I also made a pool request into original library by have not follow-up on that.

So, now basically you have MyPath property which you can read and write. The only thing you need is to store it somehow in your database. I selected to convert it to JSON back and forth once needed.

Disclaimer: as it's already more than half a year once I did it, probably some details are missing, but the library is working as I still use it in my project. For safety reason please download it or clone because I cannot guaranty, it will be there forever :)

Comment: Hi, I'm kind of desperate for this feature. I've spent some time researching your forked project, but haven't found any functionality related to saving/storing the path, neither I have found any MyPath property. 

I have gone through all your code and even looked at the commits. Are you sure you uploaded the correct version? Cheers!

Comment: Hi! You are correct - I am not really good in git. Sorry for that :-/So, now I recommitted the repo and you should be able to find it there.

Comment: Hahah I already modified the library. I discovered you can repaint the paths if you store the list of `Offset(dx, dy)` you paint with your finger, so if you store those, everything should be okay. I will also take a look at your implementation to see what you came up with. Thanks! :)

Comment: Yes, this is quite similar. if you manage to create a pool request, it would be good - I tried but failed :) Need to learn GitHub and version control better :)